# Unit Testing Views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I have used Mock to unit test ViewModels. My problem is with the views.
I have to test the KeyUp event of a textbox.

In my ViewTest class, I have the following code.

```
View1 ViewTarget = null;

[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
  ViewTarget = new Veiw1();
}

[TestMethod]
    public void searchTextBox_KeyUpTest()
    {

        TextBox element = new TextBox();
        element.RaiseEvent(
                 new KeyEventArgs(
                  Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                  Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
                  0,
                  Key.Enter) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyUpEvent }
                       );
    }
```

What do I pass as the input source? `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource` returns null. I tried mocking the PresentationSource for input source but throws a ProxyGenerationException.

Comment: Views should not have any business logic in them... that's the whole point of MVVM. Therefore, there should be no reason to test your views.

Comment: You are right. But this code was written about 2 years ago and I am asked to test it. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views should not have any business logic in them... that's the whole point of MVVM. Therefore, there should be no reason to test your views.

However, if you really want to test some logic in an event handler, just put it into another method and call that from your event handler. You will then be able to test that method separately. Take a look at this example:

```
public void searchTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandlerCode();
}
```

...

```
public void EventHandlerCode()
{
    // your handling code here
}
```

You can call `EventHandlerCode` from your unit test.

Comment: if the view has a validation logic, e.g.:

1. Hours (a text box bound to [TotalHours] in View Model) cannot be more than 24.
2. User enters 25 in that text box
3. [ErrorMessage] (A text block in the view) changes to Visible to show a VALIDATION error. 

To test that the error shows up, I do something like this:
1. In a unit test inject a mocked up View Model to an instance of the View
2. Mock [TotalHours] to 25
3. I call [Show()] and verify the visibility state of [ErrorMessage].

That's what I'm doing right now. What is the right way to do it? (I have looked in many places)

Comment: The right way is to NOT test it. You are trying to test that Microsoft validation works. But it does work. They have already tested it for us, so we don't need to. We just need to trust that they have done their job correctly, and if not, report a bug to them and let them fix it. Alternatively, use `DependencyProperty` coercion to not allow an incorrect value to be entered in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Sheridan. What I'm giving is a basic example, but sometimes the logic is a little bit more and still, only validation (Not business) logic. For example if [TextBox1] has value "x" and [TextBox2] has value "y" (still simple for example purposes), then change [Message1] to visible. The tests that I'm using now have helped us find validation failures, I think it's something that should be tested, but I don't think that logic should be in the ViewModel (I may be wrong and perhaps it should be)

Comment: All business logic should be in the View Model or Model classes at least, where it can be easily testable. Perhaps you need to look at alternative ways to validate your data, perhaps using `DataAnnotation` attributes, for example. You might prefer to start your own question to get more answers.